# Commute finite sum with finite product

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have a relation of the form:
$$\prod_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j = 1}^m a_{ij}$$
Is there any general procedure to convert this to the form:
$$\sum_{j' = 1}^{m'}\prod_{i' = 1}^{n'}b_{i'j'}$$

I have a very particular formula I want to work out, but I'd prefer to work through it myself, so just want references to general techniques (if they exist).

Comment: In the case where $a_{ij}$ is independent of $i$, the formula is the Multinomial formula, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: $$\prod_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m a_{i,j} = \sum_{e \in \{1,\ldots,m\}^n} \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i, e_i}$$ the second sum has $m^n$ terms